# Test whether all reducers have been imported in the rootReducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a rootReducer that imports all separate reducers like so:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import departments from './departments';
import indicators from './indicators';
import versions from './versions';
import projects from './projects';

// combine all reducers to a single reducer, state will be linked to a reducer via the key used here
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  versions,
  departments,
  indicators,
  projects,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Since it's important for this reducer to import everything, I think it makes sense to test whether all defined reducers in `./src/reducers` are imported. The only method I can think of would use `fs` to check the number of files in `./src/reducers` (without `index`, or the `rootReducer`) and check whether the `rootReducer` contains that many reducers.

Seems like an ugly test, and a bit fragile as well. But still it would be very nice to be notified with a failing test when you forget to include a reducer. What would be the best way to test whether all reducers have been imported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hear where you're coming from but I don't think you want to be dealing with this issue in your tests. As your application grows you're likely want a deeper reducer tree. E.g. your `projects` reducer may come to be made up of multiple sub-reducers and you'll have to manage which reducers need to be imported from where. The file system test will become more and more brittle. In general, imports and file structures are implementation details of your project and you want to be testing the behavior of your project.

But wanting immediate feedback on failing to hook up a reducer totally makes sense. I'd try to handle it at the build level. Assuming you're using Webpack maybe see if [this plugin](https://github.com/tomchentw/unused-files-webpack-plugin) can solve your problem. It detects unused exports. Add it to your plugins

```
new UnusedFilesWebpackPlugin({ pattern: 'src/reducers/**' })
```

and your build will warn you when you have a file that isn't being imported. Since it works with modules you won't have to worry about the directory structure (beyond ensuring that the pattern matches all the files you want to check).

Comment: Ah, that's a great solution! I think your distinction between implementation vs behaviour makes a lot of sense. Makes it easier to reason about what exactly to test. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The approach you suggested *might* work, but I agree that something like that would be brittle and may not even test the behavior you're concerned with.

Take a step back and look at the behavior of the code you posted.  If you were to abstract it to English, it might look something like this:

1. Import a function called `combineReducers`
2. Import each of the reducers I want to be included
3. Call `combineReducers`, and pass an object containing each of the reducers I want to be included
4. Export the result of calling `combineReducers`

It seems like you're only concerned with #3, which depends on #1 and #2 being correct.  If you want to test that `combineReducers` is called with the arguments you expect, why not stub this function and assert that behavior?

You can use SinonJS to [stub](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#stubs) `combineReducers`, and after you `require()` your root reducer, you can assert that `combineReducers` was called once, and that it was called with an Object that contains the keys and values you expect.  Here's how I might do something like that (using the `mocha` test framework, and `chai` for assertions):

```
import * as Redux from 'redux';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import chai, {expect} from 'chai';
import sinonChai from 'sinon-chai';

import departments from './departments';
import indicators from './indicators';
import versions from './versions';
import projects from './projects';

chai.use(sinonChai);

describe('Root Reducer', () => {
    before(() => {
        sinon.stub(Redux, 'combineReducers');
        require('./path/to/your/root/reducer');
    });

    after(() => {
        Redux.combineReducers.restore();
    });

    it('should use all of the created reducers', () => {
        const expectedReducers = {
            versions,
            departments,
            indicators,
            projects
        };

        expect(Redux.combineReducers).to.have.callCount(1);
        expect(Redux.combineReducers).to.be.calledWith(expectedReducers);
    });
});
```

The benefit of this approach over the one you suggested is that it doesn't rely on an arbitrary number of files present in a folder, and the variable responsible for holding on to the expected value in the test is all that needs to be modified if you want to add a new reducer or remove an old one.

Comment: Agree that testing the file system will be brittle. But If a developer adds a reducer but forgets to add it to the root reducer they definitely also forgot to update this spec, right?.

Comment: Sure, but if a developer were to remove one by accident, this would catch it.  It's a pretty trivial process to add another reducer and update this test along with it.

Comment: Indeed, removing a reducer would be caught by this test. But I think the most common occurence would be forgetting to add one. I think my goal of wanting to test this is just not something that ultimately belongs in my unit tests. As @MichaelParker suggested, it would be more at home in the build process. Thanks for your answer!